# Use images in pagination links

Tags: 7, paging

I am using drupal 7 and i am trying to override the pager.inc function like this .

```
function bartik_pager_first($variables) {
  $text = '<img src="http://localhost/drupal/themes/bartik/logo.png"></img>';
  $element = $variables['element'];
//  $parameters = $variables['parameters'];
  global $pager_page_array;
  $output = '';

  // If we are anywhere but the first page
  if ($pager_page_array[$element] > 0) {
    $output = theme('pager_link', array('text' => $text, 'page_new' => pager_load_array(0, $element, $pager_page_array), 'element' => $element, 'parameters' => $parameters));
  }

  return $output;
}
```

As you can see i am just trying to print the image for the text "first". But its just displaying like

```
<img src="http://localhost/drupal/themes/bartik/logo.png"></img>
```

How do i tell drupal that display it as html image rather then just text.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to override [theme_pager_link()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes--pager.inc/function/theme_pager_link/7) as well. The last line calls the [l()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes--common.inc/function/l/7) function and you have to force it to render html.

Another possibility is to use css to theme the links

Answer (score 1):

CSS is the proper way. Imagine you have to change the way your pagers are shown. You don't want to edit PHP for this. CSS is for the presentation layer.